# flutter android build error 'Could not find method defaultConfig() for arguments'

Tags: android, flutter, build

My android (emulator) build fails on flutter, saying theres an issue at line 36 of the build.gradle: `cannot find defaultConfig() for arguments`

The error in full looks like this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/xx..xx../android/build.gradle' line: 36

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not find method defaultConfig() for arguments [build_1ahk5maotia8z2l2hbvktzkh5$_run_closure5@32af9119] on root project 'android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

The build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
    targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Obviously the defaultConfig is there at the bottom.  It refers to the local.properties file which contains the minSDKVersion:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk
flutter.sdk=/Users/xxx/REPOs/FlutterSourceCode
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1

flutter.minSdkVersion=21
flutter.targetSdkVersion=30
flutter.compileSdkVersion=33
```

Have tried allsorts of other solutions to this but nothing seems to help.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`? Also, would you please post `flutter doctor` as well?

Comment: Yes have done flutter clean, flutter pub get lots of times.  Flutter doctor says everything is perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've changed the wrong `build.gradle` for Android, the `./android/build.gradle` instead of the `./android/app/build.gradle`. The later is the right one to use `defaultConfig` and it should be inside the `android` configuration like the following `build.gradle`:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// START: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// END: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
        targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much!  Yes that was the issue.  All these build.gradle files confusing an old iOS dev.  Thanks, have a great day.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me fix the same problem.